# FTPS explicite talend issue

Tags: ssl, talend, ftps

i can upload file on FTP server with tFTPPut Talend

SSL connection failed; session reuse required: see require_ssl_reuse option in vsftpd.conf man page

Comment: More details ??

Comment: did you try reading the man page, like the message suggests?

Comment: I tested the account by using filezilla or winSCP with the passive mode, it works fine, i can connect and upload files on server but when i want use the talend job's, it give me the error.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, when i choose FTPS option the connection mode is being invisible. it can be the problem ? coz the server is configured on the passif mode with FTPS

Comment: any answers ? i'm really blocked